# Add a tab on product page based on attribute set

Tags: product, attribute-set, tabs

I would like to add a static block on the frontend product page conditionally, based on the attribute set of the product. (e.g. Helmets -> display helmet size chart, which does not apply to other products.)

I have added:

```
<reference name='product.info.tabs'>
    <block type="cms/block" name="helmets_size_chart">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>helmets_size_chart</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

to the tabs block in local.xml, but that shows the static block on the tabs section on all product pages. 
Secondly, I've added:

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

    if (!($setId = $product->getAttributeSetId())) {
        $setId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set', null);
    }

    if($setId != 12) { // helmets
        $this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('helmets_size_chart');
    }
}
```

to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Tabs.php
When viewing the product page, I can verify indeed the code in the setId != 12 block is parsed, but the unsetBlock() call doesn't do anything.

As you may have guessed, this is my first attempt at something programmatically in Magento, and I have no clue if I'm on the right track. Any thoughts welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom block and extend from `Mage_Cms_Block_Block`

You can now do something like this:

```
class Foo_Bar_Block_Producttab extends Mage_Cms_Block_Block
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        if ($product->getAttributeSetId() == 12) {
            $this->setBlockId('helmets_size_chart');
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

And adjust your layout update file:

```
<reference name='product.info.tabs'>
    <block type="foo_bar/producttab" name="helmets_size_chart" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick!

But I'm afraid I'm still a little lost on where to add this class .. Do I create a new module for this?

Answer (score 0):

dvdmierden,you can not do this your code. Because of there have  `a logic  which is included the tab according to its format`.

if you want to then you need to customization.

Step1:

first create an module which `rewrite` Magento core class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs`

Step2:

Here add a function `addCmsBlock()` which is add a `static block` to your tab.
According magento `default tab is add by addTab()` and render tabs by functon  `getTabs()` and  it renturn

i have have create a custom function and using this function  you can add cms block add attibute set a

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Block_Product_View_Tabs  extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs{

    function addCmsBlock($alias='amit', $title='Test', $cmsblock='',$attributeset=''){

        if (!$title || !$alias || !$cmsblock ||!$attributeset) {
            return false;
        }
        // get product
         $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
         // check attribute set and not match to return false
         if($product->getAttributeSetId()!=$attributeset){
            return false;
         }
        $this->_tabs[] = array(
            'alias' => $alias,
            'title' => $title
        );

    $this->setChild($alias,$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
    ->setBlockId($cmsblock));

    }
}
```

**NOte:** I have rewrite class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs

In this function `alias name,title and cms Identifier` and `attribute set id` require field

and now can  add a tab on product page based on attribute set using below format of layout xml

```
      <action method="addCmsBlock" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>YoutAliasName</alias>
    <title>Your Title</title><cmsblock>CmsBlockIdentifier</cmsblock>
    <attributeset>YOurAttribute</attributeset></action>
```

**sample Layout code:**

```
<reference name='product.info.tabs'>
        <action method="addCmsBlock" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>Amit</alias><title>Amit Information</title>
        <cmsblock>home-decor</cmsblock><attributeset>13</attributeset>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to edit my post with the following info because it didn't work, but I figured it out; my naming convention was wrong. Below the working code:

I've now created that new module.
/app/code/local/Momi/Customproducttabs/Block/Producttab.php

```
class Momi_Customproducttabs_Block_Producttab extends Mage_Cms_Block_Block {
  protected function _toHtml() {
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if ($product->getAttributeSetId() == 12) {
        $this->setBlockId('helmets_size_chart');
    }
    return parent::_toHtml();
  }
}
```

In my theme's local.xml:

```
<reference name='product.info.tabs'>
    <block type="momi_customproducttabs/producttab" name="helmets_size_chart" />
</reference>
```